# Should I prune all the rootstock's suckers from the Cherry plant (Brooks)

Tags: pruning, root-pruning

Should I prune all the rootstock's suckers from the Cherry plant (Brooks)

[image: Brooks cherry]
[image: zoomed]

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
These suckers are wasted energy for the growth of your tree, flower and fruit formation.
This is quite common on root stock tree.
I would also suggest buying a black porous membrane to stop the suckers from coming up then mulch on top to starve of light.

Comment: User, black porous membrane will not stop suckers.  Simply cutting them off starves them of light but there is another reason that the root stock is trying to grow vegetative matter.  Yes, suckers are wasted energy for wanted flower and fruit production but they usually mean the roots need more carbohydrates being produced and provided than the grafted upper growth is able to provide at the time.  The other reason is that this cherry tree is planted too deeply. Only the root ball should be below the soil, not a bit of the trunk of this tree.